# use asterisk inside variable in zsh function

Tags: shell, zsh

In my zsh, I've defined a function

```
a() { local x=*.proto; ls "$x"; }
```

when i hit a in my terminal, got

> Specified path '*.proto' doesn't exist.

My directory ooks like:

```
hello.proto
```

How can I pass the wildcard match?

Answer (score 1):

Use an array and expand the glob results inside it using `printf()`. Like `nullglob` on `bash`, the `zsh` shell has an `null_glob` option to silently exit on expansion failure. So putting it all together

```
a() {
   # Turing on the option to prevent glob expansion failure
   setopt null_glob
   # Put the results to an array, so that a quoted expansion would keep the
   # filename containing shell meta-characters intact
   local x=(*.proto)
   # Print the array if it is non-empty.
   (( "${#a[@]}" )) && printf '%s\n' "${x[@]}"
}
```